# Jupyter notebooks limits output lines in text file. Anyway to adjust this setting>

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

The following code (copying the input file), when run in a Jupyter notebook, produces an output file with only 215,177 lines. Input file is 215,448 lines. When run externally, the file is copied exactly (215,448 lines). Why is Jupyter limiting my output file size? Is there a way to change it?

```
input_file = open('input_file.txt','r')
out = open('out.txt','w')

for line in input_file:
    linecopy = (line)
    out.write(linecopy)
```

Comment: are the 215,177 lines of the source file and the output file the same? maybe some lines get concatenated or added together?

Comment: yes the 215,177 lines of the output file are exactly the same as the output file. I did an examdiff between the two files, that's how I discovered the output was shorter than the source. Running the same code outside jupyter resulted in an exact copy of the source file.